# Should I accept also useless answers?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I specify that an answer is not the answer and thus maintain my 100% accept rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133612/how-do-i-specify-that-an-answer-is-not-the-answer-and-thus-maintain-my-100-acce)

Let's say that I make a question and I get the solution through all comments.I get only one answer and did not solve the problem.Since I can't accept a comment as answer, should I accept the useless answer to increase my accept rate?

Comment: No. Whoever's asking you to bump up your accept rate, let us know and we'll have them flogged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not accept useless answer.

If someone answer your question via comment, ask that commentator to convert his/her comment into an answer so that you can accept it.

If he/she does not reply you or does not make an answer, you can make an answer with linking those comments and make that answer CW because the question is solved by other. And accept it so feature visiting people also find the correct solutions.

> should I accept the useless answer to increase my accept rate?

- Don't feel that you need to accept an answer on *every* question.  [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) considers an accept rate of 70% or more ["quite good"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/).

Comment: This has nothing to do with this particular question specifically, I'm just curious. I've noticed you often post answers that are only links to FAQs or other MSO posts. You also seem to have a high rate of answering questions that you also vote to close. Why is that? Or am I just suffering from confirmation bias?

Comment: @PopularDemand - Not like that. I answer the question which I know. Now, I am not sure so asking you. Should I answer the duplicate question or not?

Comment: Well, if you think a question is answerable and deserves to be answered, then I don't understand why you would vote to prevent it from being answered. Regarding dupes specifically, you're wasting your own time and increasing clutter, for no real benefit (other than hoarding rep for yourself).

Comment: @PopularDemand - Okay I will keep in mind. And yes I know reputation on Meta is not (more) valuable. :)

Answer (score 7):

I would not accept a useless answer just to increase your acceptance rate.

There are two ways that you can handle this:

**First**, if no one posts an answer that truly solved your question but you solved it using the comments, then I would post an the final solution that you came up with and accept your own answer.

You can use all of the information from the comments to post a final solution to your problem. Then at least your question will have been answered.

There is nothing wrong with answering your own answer even if you got their with the help of those commenting.  You can even reference the comments in your answer so people know where you got the solution from.

**Second**, you can ask the person who commented giving you the solution to create an answer for you to accept.